# Save Core Data attribute into a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsstring

I'm trying to store a Core Data attribute into a `NSString` but I can't find a proper way.
Here is the code I use in order to set a `UITextField` text with a Core Data attribute.

```
[self.myTextField setText:[self.datas valueForKey:@"myAttribute"]];
```

where `datas` is my `NSManagedObject`

How can I do this?

EDIT:

Could be this a solution?

```
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.datas valueForKey:@"myAttribute"] ];
```

Comment: There's no such method as `setText` on `NSString`, which is why you get an error. What problem are you seeing with the first version? In what way are things not working?

Comment: Things work but i need to save an attribute on a NSString, the first method saves on a UITextfield.

Comment: Could be this a solution?
`string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.datas valueForKey:@"myAttribute"] ];`

Comment: Did you test it? I assume it would work as long as the valueForKey isn't returning nil. You don't need the string with format part you can do string = [self.datas valueForKey:@"myAttribute"]; If your proposed solution isn't working make sure you are not getting a nil returned.

Comment: @BenAvery i tested it and worked in both ways, thanks for your answer!